# How to modify composer.json for installing Gedmo Doctrine2 extensions in Symfony2

Tags: json, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to install to install the Gedmo Doctrine2 extensions in Symfony2 to use the translate composante.

I found a page online that show me how to do it (https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/symfony2.md), but I'm not shure about a few things.

First, when I change the composer.json file, I noticed that I have

```
"psr-0": { 
                "": "src/",
                "SymfonyStandard": "app/"
            }
```

And the instruction tells me to add

```
 "psr-0": {
            "Acme": "src/"
        }
```

I don't know if I need to change the  `"": "src/",`  ligne or if I add the new ligne, or if I just let it be like it is.

I would really help me if someone juste tell what my file should looks like, so here is my composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { 
                "": "src/",
                "SymfonyStandard": "app/"
            }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.6.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
        "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.12",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.0.*",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.0.*",
        "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "dev-master",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "ircmaxell/password-compat": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.6-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

The other thing is that after that step, I need to run `php composer.phar update gedmo/doctrine-extensions` in composer, but I don't have a a composer.phar file, so I did insted `composer update`.

Is that O.K., or I need to do an other line?

Comment: If you don't have a composer.phar file then you NEED to download it, otherwise you won't be able to update anything.  Get it from here: https://getcomposer.org/download/.  Once you run the `php composer.phar update gedmo/doctrine-extensions` you should be good.

Comment: thanks you, but I still have a question, do I install composer in the root directory of my project and do you have the answer to my first question?

Comment: Since you already have a composer.json file, install it in the same directory as that file.  I don't think you need to change the psr-0 section of the file, but I'm not completely sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use

```
composer require gedmo/doctrine-extensions
```

and the composer.json will be automatically modified.

Regarding "composer" vs "composer.phar": yes, they are the same, so you can use whatever you have.

To add more details: usually everyone rename "composer.phar" to "composer" and move it to a binaries location on the os (i.e. /usr/local/bin on Linux) so that it can be used as a common system command. That is probably your situation.

Answer (score 0):

The instruction is unclear, you do not need to change the line

```
"psr-0": { 
            "": "src/",
            "SymfonyStandard": "app/"
        }
```

Just add `"gedmo/doctrine-extensions":      "dev-master"` to the `require` section.

Then to run a composer update you should install [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) if you have not yet done so (but if you have symfony installed, I think you do unless you followed the instructions in the [tutorial](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/symfony2.md#symfony2-application) in which case I would reinstall symfony [the official way](http://symfony.com/download) as the tutorial refers to an outdated repository)